# How to insert NA for missing dates?

Tags: r

I have identified the missing dates, but I need to insert them in the "date" column  and put NA for all corresponding columns in the data frame.

```
      DF <- data.frame(Year = rep(1985, 4), 
             Month = rep(1, 4), 
             Day = c(1,2,5,6), 
             Z = 7:10)
     colnames(DF)[4] <- "Data"
     DF$DATE <- make_date(year = DF$Year, month = DF$Month, day = DF$Day)
     FullSeq <- seq.Date(from = min(DF$DATE), to = max(DF$DATE), by = 1)
     Missing <- FullSeq[!FullSeq %in% DF$DATE]
```

Output:

```
     Year Month Day Data       DATE
 #> 1 1985     1   1    7 1985-01-01
 #> 2 1985     1   2    8 1985-01-02
 #> 2 NA     NA   NA   NA 1985-01-03
 #> 2 NA     NA   NA   NA 1985-01-04
 #> 3 1985     1   5    9 1985-01-05
 #> 4 1985     1   6   10 1985-01-06
```

Comment: What is `FullSeq`?

Comment: THanks, edited just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tidyr::complete()`

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr) # for the pipe

  DF %>% 
  complete(DATE = FullSeq)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   DATE        Year Month   Day  Data
#>   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 1985-01-01  1985     1     1     7
#> 2 1985-01-02  1985     1     2     8
#> 3 1985-01-03    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 4 1985-01-04    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 5 1985-01-05  1985     1     5     9
#> 6 1985-01-06  1985     1     6    10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>